# AvroKey and AvroValue classes in avro-mapred lib

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, avro

Just wanted to know and check if AvroKey and AvroValue classes provided in avro-mapred library are Writables?
I am planning to reuse the objects to save some memory in mapreduce job.

Answer (score 0):

No. They are just wrapper classes. You can save memory by modifying the underlying datum.

```java
GenericData.Record record = new GenericData.Record(schema);
record.put("name", "Bob");
record.put("age", 10);
AvroKey<GenericData.Record> avroKey = new AvroKey<>(record);

context.write(avroKey, NullWritable.get());

record.put("name", "Mike");
record.put("age", 11);
context.write(avroKey, NullWritable.get());
```

Although mutable objects are common source of bugs. Consider measuring memory consumption before and after the refactoring.